# Using tail and grep in PHP Script

Tags: php

I am fetching a log file `radius.log` which is basically a large file. It contains logs for multiple users.

**First Command**

```
tail -n 20 /tmp/radius.log
```

This returns the last 20 logs. And that is what was expected from the command.

**Second Command**

```
tail -n 20 /tmp/radius.log | grep "username"
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get last 20 logs for each user as well.
Here is where I am facing the issue. It is only returning the last log (last 1 log) for the user. That is also expected because it only searches for `username` in the last 10 logs.

When I increase the number of lines to be returned say 200, I can see the remaining logs for the user.

```
tail -n 20 /tmp/radius.log | grep "username"
```

But is there a command which will only get  the last 20 logs for a particular user?

```
grep "username" /tmp/radius.log | tail -n 20
```

This solution works perfectly fine. It first gets all logs for `username` and then tails the last 20 logs. But this is a time consuming process.

Still trying for a efficient one.

Comment: Does radius.log grow infinitely ? Grep will get slower the larger the file becomes. Keeping the log as small as possible will ensure that your search will be quicker.

Answer (score 3):

You have to execute grep at first and then your tail

```
grep "username" /tmp/radius.log | tail -n 20
```

The other way with some missing results is to use tail 2 times

```
tail -n 5000 /tmp/radius.log | grep "username" | tail -n 20
```

And the other good way is to convert your log into a DB (MySQL with TokuDB)

Comment: I believe this code first gets all the logs for "username" and then tail the last 20 logs. This works, but the process consumes time. Looking for a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, the second one `tail -n 5000 /tmp/radius.log | grep "username" | tail -n 20` will satisfy the requirement of the current task. I am upvoting your answer. However, I am leaving it unaccepted so that it can be open for other solutions as well.